# Evaluate statement not working as expected

Tags: cobol

In my Cobol routine, I want to base only on the first byte of the variable `PAR-STR PIC X(12)` from Linkage section to perform a different task (argument matching).
The compiler exits with the statement, that there is more than one object to evaluate in the statement.

```
     DISPLAY PAR-STR.
     EVALUATE PAR-STR(1:1)           
       WHEN 'P'                      
       WHEN 'p'                      
         PAR-STR = "X"             
       WHEN 'L'                       
       WHEN 'l'                      
         PAR-STR = "Y"             
       WHEN OTHER PAR-STR = "Z"
```

The compile result is giving me a problem, that there is no separation by also.

From my understanding, there is only one object to evaluate. Thus, unless there is a bug in the
compiler, there is something of a cause of this proble that I'm not aware of..?

From the complier output:

```
  000010                      WHEN 'p'                                                            
                                                                                                  
==000010==> IGYPS2165-S Multiple "EVALUATE" objects were not separated by "ALSO".  The statement  
                        was discarded.                                                            
                                                                                                  
==000010==> IGYPS2133-S The number of "EVALUATE" subjects was less than the number of "EVALUATE"  
                        objects.  The statement was discarded.                                    
                                                                                                  
==000010==> IGYPA3009-S The selection object at position 1 in the "WHEN" phrase did not match the 
                        type of the corresponding selection subject in the "EVALUATE" statement.  
                        The selection object was discarded.
```

Thanks for any hint about what could be the cause of this messages shown.

Comment: A compiler bug is not likely.  More likely is a syntax error on your part.  You haven't included enough code in your question to know for sure.  Does your `EVALUATE` staement end with `END-EVALUATE` or a period?

Comment: Additional to the note above: you likely want to use `MOVE` instead of `=` for the statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does mention that there is no ALSO, but finds there is an additional expression in the first WHEN (`PAR-STR = "X"`).

The correct statements that work look accordingly:

```
     DISPLAY PAR-STR.
     EVALUATE PAR-STR(1:1)           
       WHEN 'P'                      
       WHEN 'p'                      
         MOVE "X" TO PAR-STR       
       WHEN 'L'                       
       WHEN 'l'                      
         MOVE "Y" TO PAR-STR            
       WHEN OTHER MOVE "Z" TO PAR-STR
     END-EVALUATE.
```